# Functions aside Classes - horribleness or acceptable?

Tags: python, oop

Possibly - opinion-based Question, but:

why this:

```
def func1():
    pass
def func2():
    pass

class BigClass:
    def method1(self):
        pass
    def method1(self):
        pass
    def method1(self):
        pass
```

is bad, but this:

```
class c1:
    def func1(self):
        pass
class c2:    
    def func2(self):
        pass

class BigClass:
    def method1(self):
        pass
    def method1(self):
        pass
    def method1(self):
        pass
```

is good?

Or - it's acceptable practice?

As for me - it just looks a bit... unstructured, maybe? I.e. - some small `functions()` aside big `Classes`. Especially - if they have list of parameters whilst classes usually have one-two parents name.

But what about some real meaning of this? Some additional security via "deeper" data encapsulation? Something else?

Or no difference at all?

Comment: It all depends what you are doing. You don't have to have everything in a class. I don't see what is wrong with that first example. Where did you read that was bad?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with using simple functions instead of classes. So I don't think code you have initially mentioned is inherently bad. The problem arises only when your functions becomes convoluted and complicated, then you face the need to structure the code into more functions to make it more readable. But then you end up having many functions that need to share data using arguments decreasing the code readability. That's the time when structuring your code into a class would make more sense.

This is just one of the benefit of Object Oriented Programming though. Believe me there are many others. I have seen many people stating that Python code need not to be Object Oriented, it is a "JAVAish" kind of approach. But nothing could be more wrong, Object Orientation(or other programming pattern for that matter) has nothing to do with a particular language. I agree that OOP is not always the best solution for the problem, but most of the time it is.